package defined materialization not reconigzed
I have a dbt package that contains a custom materialization to adapt the bigquery one.
Here's the folder structure:
dbt_packages
 ┣ custom_packages
 ┃ ┣ macros
 ┃ ┃ ┣ materializations
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ bigquery
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ incremental_strategy
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ custom_merge.sql
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ merge_with_audit.sql
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ utils.sql
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ docs.yml
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ incremental.sql


I've defined a custom incremental_strategy (my_merge_strategy) in the same way of bigquery one. When I run the model I got the error:
Invalid incremental strategy provided: my_merge_strategy
      Expected one of: 'merge', 'insert_overwrite'

The problem seems kinda basic because if the folder materialization is inside my local projet macro folder everything works fine. But when it's inside the package the custom materialization is not recognized.
I've already tried to add the dispatch attribute in dbt_project.yml because the default bigquery materialization is inside the dbt package.
dispatch:
  - macro_namespace: dbt
    search_order: ['custom_package', 'dbt']

However it doesn't work either.
How can I specify to use the materialization inside of the custom_package ?
